# Python split byte into high & low nibbles

Tags: python, pyserial, nibble

I am trying to send and receive rs232 data using pyserial but I don't understand how to properly send the correct data. What little information I have explains the data string and says that it should be split into high and low nibbles. The converting to nibbles is that part I don't get, I tried to read up on it but don't get how to do use it for my case.

So I have this Data string to send over serial.
10,00,00,00,00,00,16,0A,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,50

It says to split the bytes into high and low nibbles, the 21 bytes are then converted into a data string of 42 characters.

Could someone help explain how to do this for me?

Comment: Besides not having tried, this sounds like homework?

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried but don't fully understand enough to make it work. I sort of get how it goes to a high and low byte but is it each character? So "ab" would have 2 bytes for a and 2 for b? That is probably wrong so that's why I asked for help. I wish it was homework and had a teacher I could just ask.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 12):

If you wanted to get the high and low nibble of a byte. In other words split the 8-bits into 4-bits.

Considering the data string is a string of bytes as hexadecimals, then you could simply do:

```
high, low = byte[:1], byte[1:2]
print(high, low)
```

Which for `byte = "16"` would print `1 6`. You can then use `int(high, 16)` and `int(low, 16)` to convert it to decimals.

If you've already converted the hexadecimal into a decimal using `int(byte, 16)` then you can extract the high and low nibble by doing:

```
high, low = byte >> 4, byte & 0x0F
print(hex(high), hex(low))
```

Which for `byte = 0x16` would print `0x1 0x6` because they're converted back to hexadecimals using `hex(x)`. *Note that `hex(x)` adds a `0x` prefix. You can remove it by doing `hex(x)[2:]`.*

So considering your data string as:

```
bytes = "10,00,00,00,00,00,16,0A,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,50"
```

Then to print each high and low nibble could be done with something like this:

```
bytes = "10,00,00,00,00,00,16,0A,20,20,20,20,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,50"
bytes = bytes.split(",")

for byte in bytes:
    byte = int(byte, 16)
    high, low = byte >> 4, byte & 0x0F

    print(hex(byte), hex(high), hex(low))
```

*Which yields the byte, high nibble and low nibble all in hexadecimals.*

Also if you have it in bits (`"{0:08b}".format(byte)`) then you can split it like this `high, low = bits[:4], bits[4:8]`, now `high, low` each having their 4-bits.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if an answer will help you now, but you can also solve this with a so called bit mask

for example split each char from a string in it's high nibble (hl) and low nibble (ln) with python:

```
input_text = "a fucking amazing input text"
for c in input_text:
  print(bin(ord(c)))
  nh = ord(c) & 0x0F
  nl = ord(c) >> 4 & 0x0F
  print("nh: " + bin(nh))
  print("nl: " + bin(nl))
```

Why 0x0F, it's 00001111

For example:

Mask:   00001111 (0x0F)
Value:  11010101
Result: 00000101

Hope that is still helpfull.